# JavaScript: Subtracting ranges of numbers

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to write a JS function which has two parameters, include and exclude, each an array of objects {X, Y} which represents a range of numbers from X to Y, both included.

The output is the subtraction of all the ranges in include with all the ranges in exclude.

For example:

```
include = [ {1,7}, {9,10}, {12,14} ]
exclude = [ {4,5}, {11,20} ]
output  = [ {1,3}, {6,7}, {9,10} ]
```

- {4,5} broke {1,7} into two range objects: {1,3} and {6,7}
- {9,10} was not affected
- {12,14} was removed entirely

Comment: So you were trying. Can you show us your code, please? And what's your question, are you stuck anywhere?

Comment: I don't see any *from* or *to* in the example. Also, will ranges always be sorted as in the example?

Comment: Are the ranges in `include` and `exclude` disjoint?

Comment: @Bergi At the moment I don't have the slighest idea how to approach that. Also I was hoping JS might have some useful shortcuts for that.

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo The numbers represent from and to, I just omitted them. The ranges might not be sorted as well, but I assume that I can be easily solved.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: the ranges in `include` do they have any intersection with each other? for example could there be `{1,7},{5,20}` in it.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 Yes that's an option.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @GabeL, please clarify if you are working strictly with integers or will you also have decimal numbers too? Also, will you be working with negative numbers too?

Comment: @GabeL: No, JS does not have many tools or "shortcuts" dedicated for this. This is a pure algorithm assignment. You should start by sorting the inputs, and then create the outputs one after the other. Do it recursively.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sweep line algorithm. For every number save what it represents (start and end, inclusion and exclusion ). Then put all the number in an array and sort it. Then iteratively remove elements from the array and perform the appropriate operation.

```
include_list = [[1,7]]
exclude_list = [[4,5]]
(1,start,inclusion),(4,start,exclusion),(5,end,exclusion),(7,end,inclusion)

include = 0
exclude = 0
cur_element = (1,start,inclusion) -> include = 1, has_open_range = 1, range_start = 1 // we start a new range starting at 1
cur_element = (4,start,exclusion) -> exclude = 1, has_open_range = 0, result.append ( [1,4] ) // we close the open range and add range to result
cur_element = (5,end,exclusion) -> exclude = 0, has_open_range = 1, range_start = 5 // because include was 1 and exclude become 0 we must create a new range starting at 5
cur_element = (7,end,inclusion) -> include = 0, has_open_range = 0, result.append([5,7]) // include became zero so we must close the current open range so we add [5,7] to result
```

maintain variables `include` and `exclude` increment them with start of the respective elements and decrement them upon receiving end elements. According to the value of `include` and `exclude` you can determine wether you should start a new range, close the open range, or do nothing at all.

This algorithm runs in linear time O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that works with fractions and that isnt just brute forcing. I've added comments to explain how it works. It may seem big the the premise is simple:

1. create a method `p1_excluding_p2` that accepts points `p1` and `p2` and returns of an array of points that exist after doing `p1 - p2`
2. create a method `points_excluding_p2` which performs the EXACT same operation as above, but this time allow us to pass an array of `points`, and return an array of points that exist after subtracting `p2` from all the points in our array, so now we have `(points) - p2`
3. create a method `p1_excluding_all` which takes the opposite input as above. This time, accept one point `p1` and many exclusion points, and return the array of points remaining after subtracting all the exclusion points. This is actually very easy to create now. We simply start off with `[p1]` and the first exclusion point (`exclusion1`) and feed this into `points_excluding_p2`. We take the array that comes back (which will be `p1 - exclusion1`) and feed *this* into `points_excluding_p2` only this time with `exclusion2`. We continue this process until we've excluded every exclusion point, and we're left with an array of `p1 - (all exclusion points)`
4. now that we have the power to perform `p1 - (all exclusion points)`, its just a matter of looping over all our points and calling `p1_excluding_all`, and we're left with an array of every point subtract every exclusion point. We run our results through `remove_duplicates` incase we have any duplicate entries, and that's about it.

The code:

```
var include = [ [1,7], [9,10], [12,14] ]
var exclude = [ [4,5], [11,20] ]

/* This method is just a small helper method that takes an array 
 * and returns a new array with duplicates removed
 */

function remove_duplicates(arr) {
  var lookup = {};
  var results = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var el = arr[i];
    var key = el.toString();
    if(lookup[key]) continue;
    lookup[key] = 1;
    results.push(el);
  }
  return results;
}

/* This method takes 2 points p1 and p2 and returns an array of
 * points with the range of p2 removed, i.e. p1 = [1,7]
 * p2 = [4,5] returned = [[1,3],[6,7]]
 */

function p1_excluding_p2(p1, p2) {
  if(p1[1] < p2[0]) return [p1]; // line p1 finishes before the exclusion line p2
  if(p1[0] > p2[1]) return [p1]; // line p1 starts after exclusion line p1
  var lines = [];
  // calculate p1 before p2 starts
  var line1 = [ p1[0], Math.min(p1[1], p2[0]-1) ];
  if(line1[0] < line1[1]) lines.push(line1);
  // calculate p1 after p2 ends
  var line2 = [ p2[1]+1, p1[1] ];
  if(line2[0] < line2[1]) lines.push(line2);
  // these contain the lines we calculated above
  return lines;
}

/* this performs the exact same operation as above, only it allows you to pass
 * multiple points (but still just 1 exclusion point) and returns results
 * in an identical format as above, i.e. points = [[1,7],[0,1]]
 *  p2 = [4,5] returned = [[0,1],[1,3],[6,7]]
 */

function points_excluding_p2(points, p2) {
  var results = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var lines = p1_excluding_p2(points[i], p2);
    results.push.apply(results, lines); // append the array lines to the array results
  }
  return results;
}

/* this method performs the same operation only this time it takes one point
 * and multiple exclusion points and returns an array of the results.
 * this is the important method of: given 1 point and many
 * exclusion points, return the remaining new ranges
 */

function p1_excluding_all(p1, excluded_pts) {
  var checking = [p1];
  var points_leftover = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < exclude.length; i++) {
    checking = points_excluding_p2(checking, exclude[i]);
  }
  return remove_duplicates(checking);
}

/* now that we have a method that we can feed a point and an array of exclusion
 * points, its just a simple matter of throwing all our points into this
 * method, then at the end remove duplicate results for good measure
 */

var results = [];
for(var i = 0; i < include.length; i++) {
  var lines = p1_excluding_all(include[i], exclude);
  results.push.apply(results, lines); // append the array lines to the array results
}
results = remove_duplicates(results);

console.log(results);
```

which returns:

```
[[1,3],[6,7],[9,10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
function excludeRange(data, exclude) {
  data = [...data] // i don't want inplace edit

  exclude.forEach(e=>{
    data.forEach((d,di)=>{
      // check intersect
      if (d[0] <= e[1] && e[0] <= d[1]) {
        // split into two range: [Ax, Bx-1] and [By+1, Ay]
        var ranges = [
          [d[0], e[0]-1],
          [e[1]+1, d[1]],
        ]
        // keep only valid range where x <= y
        ranges = ranges.filter(e=>e[0]<=e[1])
        // replace existing range with new ranges
        data.splice(di, 1, ...ranges)
      }
    })
  })
  return data
}
```

I try to implement this short and simple as possible

---

edit: add explain and update more readable code

the algorithm with A-B

- if intersect -> we split into two range: [Ax, Bx-1] and [By+1, Ay]

  - then we filter out invalid range (where x > y)
- else: keep A

Comment: Welcome to SO! This potentially good answer would really benefit from some explanation what each line does exactly. I would also recommend using more ; for readability :)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: `include = [ {1,7}, {9,10}, {12,14} ]` is not valid javascript, so I assumed you as passing in arrays of arrays instead such as:

```
 include = [ [1,7], [9,10], [12,14] ]
```

Brute force method (a solution, may not be the most eloquent):

```
function solve_range(include, exclude) {
    numbers = [];
    include.forEach(function (range) {
        for (i = range[0]; i <= range[1]; i++) {
            numbers[i] = true;
        }
    });

    exclude.forEach(function (range) {
        for (i = range[0]; i <= range[1]; i++) {
            numbers[i] = false;
        }
    });

    contiguous_start = null;

    results = [];

    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] === true) {
            if (contiguous_start == null) {
                contiguous_start = i;
            }
        } else {
            if (contiguous_start !== null) {
                results[results.length] = [contiguous_start, i - 1];
            }
            contiguous_start = null;
        }
    }

    return results;
}

var include = [
    [1, 7],
    [9, 10],
    [12, 14]
];
var exclude = [
    [4, 5],
    [11, 20]
];

var output = solve_range(include, exclude);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dwyk631d/2/

Comment: The OP's example dataset did not include anything except integers nor did he specify that it was any other data besides integers.

Answer (score 0):

The rule for integer set arithmetic for subtraction of two sets `X,Y` is

```
X − Y := {x − y | x ∈ X, y ∈ Y }
```

but that's not what you want, as it seems.

You can assume ordered sets in your example which allows you to set every occurrence of `x==y` as an arbitrary value in a JavaScript array and use that to split there. But you don't need that.

The set difference `{1...7}\{4...5}` gets expanded to `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}\{4,5}`. As you can easily see, a subtraction with the rule of set arithmetic would leave `{1,2,3,0,0,6,7}` and with normal set subtraction (symbol `\`) you get `{1,2,3,6,7}`.

The set difference `{12...14}\{11...20}` gets expanded to `{12,13,14}\{11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}`; the set arithm. difference is {-11,0,0,0,-15,-16,...,-20} but the normal set-subtraction leaves the empty set `{}`.

Handling operations with the empty set is equivalent to normal arithmetic `{x}-{}={x}` and `{}-{x} = {-x}` for arithmetic set rules and `{x}\{}={x}`,`{}\{x}= {}` with normal rules

So what you have to use here, according to your example, are the normal set rules. There is no need to expand the sets, they can be assumed to be dense.

You can use relative differences(you may call them distances).

With `{1...7}\{4...5}` the first start is small then the second start and the first end is greater the the second end, which resulted in two different sets.

With `{12...14}\{11...20}` the first start is greater than the second start and the first end is lower then the second end which resulted in an empty set.

The third example makes use of the empty-set rule.

Do you need an example snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution that handles the 4 possible overlap scenarios for an exclusion range.

```
var include = [{from:1, to: 7},{from: 9, to: 10},{from: 12, to: 14}];
     var exclude = [{from:4, to: 5}, {from: 11, to: 20}];

     //result: {1,3}, {6,7}, {9,10}

     var resultList = [];

     for (var i=0;i<include.length;i++){

         var inc = include[i];
         var overlap = false;

         for (var x=0;x<exclude.length;x++ ){

             var exc = exclude[x];

             //4 scenarios to handle

             if (exc.from >= inc.from && exc.to <= inc.to){
                 //include swallows exclude - break in two
                 resultList.push({from: inc.from, to: exc.from - 1});
                 resultList.push({from: exc.to + 1, to: inc.to});
                 overlap = true;
             }else if (exc.from <= inc.from && exc.to >= inc.to){
                 //exclude swallows include - exclude entire range
                 overlap = true;
                 break;
             }else if (exc.from <= inc.from && exc.to <= inc.to && exc.to >= inc.from){
                 //exclusion overlaps on left
                 resultList.push({from: exc.to, to: inc.to});
                 overlap = true;
             }else if (exc.from >= inc.from && exc.to >= inc.to && exc.from <= inc.to){
                 //exclusion overlaps on right
                 resultList.push({from: inc.from, to: exc.from - 1});
                 overlap = true;
             }

         }

         if (!overlap){
             //no exclusion ranges touch the inclusion range
             resultList.push(inc);
         }
     }
     console.log(resultList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can make it slightly more efficient by merging labeled intervals into one sorted list:

```
include = [ {1,7}, {9,10}, {12,14} ]    
exclude = [ {4,5}, {11,20} ]

merged = [ [1,7,0], [4,5,1], [9,10,0], [11,20,1], [12,14,0] ];
```

Then, traverse the list and for any excluded interval, update any surrounding affected intervals.